# Talend job not running

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend.

I created my first job, and ran it.

I followed [this](https://www.talendbyexample.com/my-first-talend-job.html) link. But, the job is not running and I get the following error :

> Execution failed : generationManager is not initialized by the perljet/javajet!

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Have you install Java correctly or any other job is running  ?

Comment: try to install all additionnal package : help > Additionnal package

Comment: @HiteshMundra how can I check whether any  other job is running?

Comment: @ThéoCapdet additional components are downloaded from talendforge.org. I am not being able to access it. Is there any other website ?

Comment: @Nishil Try to create and run any simple talend job for ex- random row print using tlogrow or test db connection by tmysqlconnection or any.

Comment: okay, I'll see if it works. thanks.

Comment: Now, I am getting the error : The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.Map$Entry. Fix the build path then try building this project .Java  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: @HiteshMundra any idea about this error?

Comment: @Nishil First check your java. Create a sample hello program on any where and try to run this with default PATH variable value. Its for check of Path variable is set correct or not.

Comment: Path Variable's value has the java version set to jdk1.7.0_45 . Should i Change it?

Comment: Check your Talend studio is compatible with Java version. Have you successfully ran the any java code ?

Comment: I checked this link : http://garpitmzn.blogspot.in/2015/09/configure-java-path-for-talend-open.html
I also changed the mentioned variables here :  TOS_DI-win-x86_64.ini . Now, talend studio is not responding

Comment: @HiteshMundra The job is now working fine, but I am not able to see any output. The MappedEmployee.csv file is empty

Comment: @Nishil You need to check your column mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

At first, the problem was that I wasn't running the appropriate version of Talend according to my 64-bit Windows OS. To do that, I had to run the "TOS_DI-win-x86_64" application from the installation directory. That solved the problem of incompatibility with the Jdk, and I was able to run my job successfully.